# Is it ok to close as duplicate of closed/downvoted question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I've just closed a question as insta-duplicate of a closed (and heavily downvoted due to original quality) question. Should I have instead search for other better looking/open match or do something else altogether?

Clearly I should not be answering again with copy-paste of my other answer. I also feel that simple downvote due to quality/close as "not enough details to debug" would waste effort of other people...

- Post in question: [C#, integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469728/c-integer-overflow?noredirect=1)
- The duplicate: [Why does computing factorial of relatively small numbers (34+) return 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222207/why-computing-factorial-of-realtively-small-numbers-34-returns-0) (The easiest to find duplicate for me as *I've edited/answered* it long time ago).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it is.

Whether a question is a duplicate or not is not related to its (or the target's) quality.

Comment: Though if _any_ of the questions are worth keeping around, it's ideal to use the best question as the master, regardless of chronology.

Comment: @JoshCaswell not the best answer?

Comment: Fair point, @I3arnon. How about the question/answer pair that maximizes the goodness function?

Answer (score 0):

Is it okay to close a question as a duplicate of another closed question?

Not, it is not. **It should only be allowed to close a question as a duplicate if the question you're redirecting people to is not also closed or a duplicate.**

When you close a question as a duplicate, the intent is to redirect people who'd like to add an answer to the original, prior question so that they can add their answer to the earlier one instead, if necessary. The point is to make a set of "canonical" Q&As that become referenced on Stack Overflow again and again.

By redirecting someone to yet another closed question, you've missed the whole point of Stack Overflow and prevented the person from answering on either question. This is especially bad when the "duplicate" question you link to has no duplicate itself, and a potential answerer is left with no place they can answer.

---

Trivial example:

1. [How to store both integers and strings in a vector? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77629875/4561887) - closed as duplicate:

   [image]
2. The above question points to this one: [In C++ when should we use std::any, std::variant or std::optional? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64479978/4561887), which is closed and does not redirect to any open question:

   [image]

This should not be allowed. **It should only be allowed to close a question as a duplicate if the question you're redirecting people to is not also closed or a duplicate.**

Comment: What if someone asks a question, it's closed as a duplicate then they ask the same question again. Surely you'd close as a duplicate of the identical question they just asked? The other problem is if someone closes a as a duplicate of b then someone else wants to close b as a duplicate of c is that OK?

Comment: You probably should post this as new question (editing for look like a proposal) linking to this question to allow for proper discussion/answers as this "close as duplicate or to have closed target" policy is quite old. Make sure to cover cases pointed out by Robert and also cases where both new and duplicate questions are off-topic (it is faster to close as duplicate than other off-topic reasons).

Comment: Often is the case is a second question will be asked, will be closed as a duplicate, but a third question that’s actually higher quality ends up being asked.  That third question ends up being answered and the first question ends up being closed after the second question. The fact the third question is answered is a different discussion.

Comment: Not sure about the dupe chains ( they can add useful context along the way) but dupe-closing towards an "off-topic" (including lack of details etc.) is somewhat fishy indeed.

Comment: "*When you close a question as a duplicate, the intent is to redirect people who'd like to add an answer to the original, prior question*" This is incorrect. The intent is to redirect people, **regardless of their goal**, to a prior question, *which already has answers*. It is not a "post your answer there" signpost, it is "this is already answered elsewhere" signpost. Also, most people who view questions are looking to find an answer, not post an answer.

Comment: @TylerH, countless times, the "prior question", which supposedly already has answers, doesn't answer the new question, or is incomplete, or only partially correct, and a new answer is needed. As the person seeking for the answer, and whose question was just closed "as a duplicate", when I see it isn't there, I then 1) feel frustrated with Stack Overflow, 2) figure it out with great effort anyway, and 3) look for a place to write down my findings as an answer (preferably on Stack Overflow). If 3 is thwarted, which it frequently is, that's not good for anybody.

Comment: @GabrielStaples That sounds like a poor duplicate closure, then, not a change in what the duplicate system is designed for.

Comment: @TylerH, then I'd submit that a huge percentage of closures on Stack Overflow are "poor duplicate closures." There is a problem. I'd like to fix it. A change on how people view closures, per my answer here, could help.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Not really the right way to do it. If you want the system to change, collect some real data, post a discussion question here, solicit feedback. As a party of one (especially when talking about your own experiences) the chances are high that you are simply mistaken/don't understand how a dupe target addresses a problem you have (or you/the closed question asker has not sufficiently clarified how their question is different). As well, if you have a specific example of an incorrectly closed question, you can vote to reopen it or bring it to Meta, too.